# When is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ not an UFD (for $d>1$)?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I was wondering if there is a classification for this:

> For which $d$ is $D=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ a UFD, with $d > 1$?

For $d \equiv 1 $ (mod $ 4$), $D$ is not a UFD (proof [here](http://mathhelpforum.com/number-theory/130093-prove-z-sqrt-d-not-ufd-when-d-1-mod-4-a.html)).

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51667

Answer (score 4):

When $d \not\equiv 1\; (\textrm{mod}\; 4)$, the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is a UFD if and only if it has trivial class group (i.e., the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is $1$).

However, it's an open question as to whether or not there are infinitely many $d>0$ with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ having class number 1, so the answer is not known.

Comment: The first sentence assumes $d$ is square-free. Also, while there's no classification, there is a list of some known UFDs ([here](http://oeis.org/A219361)).