# is there any subset of the reals that is not a Unique Factorization Domain?

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

Is there any subset of the real numbers that is not a Unique Factorization Domain?  (i.e. where within that subset, a "prime" is a number that cannot be written as a product of any numbers in that set except itself and 1, and where there is at least one number that can be written as the product of two different sets of primes).

I usually introduce recreational math students to the concept of a non-UFD by showing them the set of all numbers a + i*b*sqrt(5).  So I wondered if you can do it without complex numbers, i.e. find a subset of the reals that is a non-UFD, or prove that it's impossible.

Comment: I assume you mean "subring", not just "subset".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ not an UFD (for $d\ge 1$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726826/when-is-mathbbz-sqrtd-not-an-ufd-for-d1)

Comment: Then take $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$ instead of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. Both are not UFD, and the first one consists of real numbers only.

Comment: $2\times 3=(1-\sqrt{-5})(1+\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: Note that it's somehow easier to show that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not UFD, because there are not many units.

Comment: @WhatsUp Well, a factorial ring would integrally closed, and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$ is not integrally closed. This is easy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suppose the audience don't have knowledge of e.g. integrally closed. But yes it's not the maximal order.

Comment: [Here](https://yutsumura.com/the-quadratic-integer-ring-zsqrt5-is-not-a-unique-factorization-domain-ufd/) is an elementary proof that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$ is not factorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked the subset of real numbers, so I'll give an example $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$.

In that case, $2, -2, 1\pm\sqrt5$ is all prime, but $-2\times2=(1-\sqrt5)(1+\sqrt5)$.

So, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$ is surely subring of $\mathbb R$, but it is not UFD.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, then $9=3\cdot3=(1+\sqrt{10})(\sqrt{10}-1)$ and $3, 1+\sqrt{10}, \sqrt{10} - 1$ are all prime numbers in this ring (although the proof of them being prime is far from obvious). Also, please notice in this context 'subset' doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I see, then let me correct my mistake.

Comment: "Far from obvious" depends on the prerequisites one has. Anyway, it is shown in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448942/proving-mathbbz-sqrt-10-is-not-a-ufd?rq=1) here.